# Setting standoff of axis label in 3d plot in plotly (ticks labels overlap with axis label)

Tags: python, plot, label, plotly, axis-labels

In case of 2d charts in plotly we can set standoff of axis label by setting `standoff` property (example: https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-space-beetween-axis-title-and-values/32218), but in case of 3d plots there is no property `standoff` because axis have to specified as dictionary values of `scene`, the problem is custom ticks labels overlap with axis label:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

ticktext = ["tick labels X"] * 3

layout = go.Layout(
         scene = dict(
                    xaxis = dict(
                        title=dict(text='xaxis'
                                   #, standoff=20 # don't work
                                  ),
                        tickvals=list(range(len(ticktext))),
                        ticktext=ticktext,
                    ),
                    yaxis = dict(
                        title='yaxis',
                        tickvals=list(range(len(ticktext))),
                        ticktext=ticktext,
                    ),
                    zaxis = dict(
                        title='zaxis',
                    )
         ),
)

# chart
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,1,2],[3,1,2]])

plotly_input_data = []
plotly_input_data.append(go.Surface(z = data + 1, showscale=False, opacity=0.9))
plotly_input_data.append(go.Surface(z = data**2-6, showscale=False, opacity=1.0))

fig = go.Figure(data=plotly_input_data, layout = layout)
fig.show()
```

[image]

This is '4.13.0' version of plotly.

**Edition**

Also using `fig.layout.xaxis.title.standoff = 20` does not work.